# If and Else help; python

Tags: python, if-statement, input

i am new to the programming, and i learned basic commands, now i tried to create something like a quizz, so here is my code which is giving me a headache...

```
 prvo =input("How much is 5+5? ")
if (prvo)==10:
    print("Correct!")
else:
    print ("Sorry, but the answer isn't correct!")
    sys.exit()
```

When i enter 10 it says:
"Sorry but the answer isn't correct!", same with every other number, help please. And can you please explain me what's wrong with it, because i really want to learn :)

Comment: `if provo == '10':` because you're comparing `provo` (a string) against `'10'` a string. if you try `10 == 10` that will be true, but doing `'10' == 10` will be false, because they're of different data [types](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str).

Comment: Convert prvo to `int`. Should be `prvo = int(input("How much is 5+5? "))`

Comment: @AndMar Will raise an exception if the input is `moo`.

Comment: @Torxed, Yes, but program expected `int`

Comment: As is your code will raise an exception before then. Indention levels don't match. In python matching indentation is mandatory

Comment: @AndMar Will still crash if you happen to enter `q` instead of a `1` and are to quick on the keys.

Comment: @Torxed you're absolutely right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either try `if prvo == str(10):`
 or as mentioned above use `prvo = int(input("How much is 5 + 5? "))`

The reason is because you're currently trying to compare two different data types. This will not work so you'll need to make sure that the data types that you're comparing are the same type.

Answer (score 1):

The `input` function takes strings as input, so the return value from `input` should be converted to type `int` and compared. The first line in your code should be

`prvo = int(input("How much is 5+5? "))`

Answer (score 0):

Input always returns a string.

Try converting 10 to a string before you compare it to the input:

```
prvo = input("How much is 5+5? ")
if prvo == str(10):
    print("Correct!")
else:
    print ("Sorry, but the answer isn't correct!")
```

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing a integer with a string (by default input() takes a string).

You can easily check this with type() :

```
prvo = input("How much is 5+5? ")
print(type(prvo))
```

This will return :

```
<class 'str'>
```

*str* meaning string.

To make it easy, I would just put 10 in quotes to make it a string too. Also you're not required to put prvo in brackets when you start the if statement.

So something like this :

```
import sys

prvo = input("How much is 5+5? ")

if prvo == "10":
    print("Correct!")
else:
    print ("Sorry, but the answer isn't correct!")
    sys.exit()
```